# Getting maximum values from a set of numbers in a ratio

Tags: ratio

I need to keep a set of five elements [a:b:c:d:e] in a ratio of [2:1:3:2:1].

I have a collection of [2035, 1050, 3060, 2040, 1027].

I need to take maximum amount of the elements according to ratio and keep the rest separately.

| **ELEMENT** | **RATIO** | **TOTAL Collection** | **RATIO WISE QTY** | **REMAINDER** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 2 | 2035 | ? | ? |
| **b** | 1 | 1050 | ? | ? |
| **c** | 3 | 3060 | ? | ? |
| **d** | 2 | 2040 | ? | ? |
| **e** | 1 | 1027 | ? | ? |

I do it this way...
[image: I do it this way]

| **ELEMENT** | **RATIO** | **TOTAL COLLECTION** | **RATIO WISE QTY** | **REMAINDER** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 2 | 2035 | 2034 | 1 |
| **b** | 1 | 1050 | 1017 | 33 |
| **c** | 3 | 3060 | 3051 | 9 |
| **d** | 2 | 2040 | 2034 | 6 |
| **e** | 1 | 1027 | 1017 | 10 |

How can I build an algorithm to get the last two column value from the first three columns.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I have edited and added screenshot how I tried it. But I'm trying to make a very precised algorithm/formula.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an easier solution:

1. We divide *Col C* by *Col B* and ignore the decimal points and store the FLOOR value into *Col D*
2. We find the minimum value from the values in *Col D* and store it into *Col E*.
3. We multiply *Col E* with *Col B* and store it into *Col F* which is our expected value.
4. We deduct *Col F* from *Col C* and store it into *Col G* and this is our another expected value.

Thus we get rid of long-stairs calculation and find solution in a easy way.

| **A** | **B** | **C** | **D=FLOOR(C/B)** | **E=MIN([D])** | **F=E*B** | **G=C-F** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **a** | 2 | 2035 | 1017 |  | 2034 | 1 |
| **b** | 1 | 1050 | 1050 | *MIN(D1:D5)* | 1017 | 33 |
| **c** | 3 | 3060 | 1020 | **1017** | 3051 | 9 |
| **d** | 2 | 2040 | 1020 |  | 2034 | 6 |
| **e** | 1 | 1027 | 1027 |  | 1017 | 10 |

Still searching for more easier solution if any...

Answer (score 0):

I think (until some one with a better idea comes along) - you essentially have an optimisation problem. To solve this in a naive way, would be to solve with a binary search, where you choose an upper boundary

```
l = #some lower bound
r = 1050 + 1 # the unitary value e.g. ratio = 1 max value 
min_diff = # some sufficiently large number
while l <= r:
   mid = (l + r) //2
   cur_diff = condition(mid)
   if cur_diff < min_diff:
      min_diff = cur_diff
      best_unitary_value = mid
      l += 1
   else:
      r -= 1
```

where `best_unitary_value` will then be equivalent to `1017`

the condition could look like

```
def condition(mid, ratios, totals):
   diff = 0
   for _, ratio in ratios:
       diff += (total - ratio * mid) 
       if ratio * mid > total:
           # this ensures we are larger than any other value
           return float('inf')
       
   return diff
```

If we have lots of values, then you can use regression with a condition on the output.